# How can I round the corners of a slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using the basic slider, and I found how to update just the parts of the slider theme data that I want to change like trackHeight, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to update the field for "trackShape".  Here is what I do in the main app to update track height for example:

```
final SliderThemeData tweakedSliderTheme = Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.copyWith(
    trackHeight: 22.0,
     //trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),  // How do I update this??
);
```

I did try using [ClipRRect()](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI43jkQkrvs) around the slider widget and that had no effect.

Here is a simple page for one slider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoomControl extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RoomControlState createState() => _RoomControlState();
}

class _RoomControlState extends State<RoomControl> {
  double _value = 0.0;
  void _setvalue(double value) => setState(() => _value = value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Name here'),
      ),
      //hit Ctrl+space in intellij to know what are the options you can use in flutter widgets
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Value: ${(_value * 100).round()}'),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              child:Slider(
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: _setvalue,
                  divisions: 10,
              )
    )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what that slider looks like:

[image]

UPDATE:
After getting the answer, I was able to create something like this easily by updating the tick mark shape, and the thumb shape:

[image]

```
final SliderThemeData tweakedSliderTheme = Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.copyWith(
  trackHeight: 20.0,
  thumbShape: MyRoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 13.0, disabledThumbRadius: 13.0),
  trackShape: MyRoundSliderTrackShape(),  // TODO: this is hard coded right now for 20 track height
  inactiveTrackColor: lightGreySliderColor,
  activeTickMarkColor: Color(blackPrimaryValue),
  inactiveTickMarkColor: colorizedMenuColor,
  tickMarkShape: MyRectSliderTickMarkShape(tickMarkRadius: 4.0),
);
```

There was a bit of a trick to the tick mark shape.  If you make it too big it just skips painting it!  Probably makes sense but I didn't know much about paint/rendering so it took me a while to learn how to get the tick marks (Rect) to show up properly

Comment: Do you have a code example of the MyRectSliderTickMarkShape?

Comment: @ErwindeGier it's been a while, but I created it like this:  "class MyRectSliderTickMarkShape extends SliderTickMarkShape { // code here }".  if you can find the original SliderTickMarkShape you can use that code or tweak it's look like I probably did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Image of Slider with Rounded Corners]
I've copied the base code from `RectangularSliderTrackShape` into a new class called `RoundSliderTrackShape`.

round_slider_track_shape.dart

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {
  /// Create a slider track that draws 2 rectangles.
  const RoundSliderTrackShape({ this.disabledThumbGapWidth = 2.0 });

  /// Horizontal spacing, or gap, between the disabled thumb and the track.
  ///
  /// This is only used when the slider is disabled. There is no gap around
  /// the thumb and any part of the track when the slider is enabled. The
  /// Material spec defaults this gap width 2, which is half of the disabled
  /// thumb radius.
  final double disabledThumbGapWidth;

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled,
    bool isDiscrete,
  }) {
    final double overlayWidth = sliderTheme.overlayShape.getPreferredSize(isEnabled, isDiscrete).width;
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    assert(overlayWidth >= 0);
    assert(trackHeight >= 0);
    assert(parentBox.size.width >= overlayWidth);
    assert(parentBox.size.height >= trackHeight);

    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + overlayWidth / 2;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    // TODO(clocksmith): Although this works for a material, perhaps the default
    // rectangular track should be padded not just by the overlay, but by the
    // max of the thumb and the overlay, in case there is no overlay.
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - overlayWidth;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }


  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    RenderBox parentBox,
    SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isDiscrete,
    bool isEnabled,
  }) {
    // If the slider track height is 0, then it makes no difference whether the
    // track is painted or not, therefore the painting can be a no-op.
    if (sliderTheme.trackHeight == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Assign the track segment paints, which are left: active, right: inactive,
    // but reversed for right to left text.
    final ColorTween activeTrackColorTween = ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor , end: sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
    final ColorTween inactiveTrackColorTween = ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor , end: sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor);
    final Paint activePaint = Paint()..color = activeTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()..color = inactiveTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
    Paint leftTrackPaint;
    Paint rightTrackPaint;
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        leftTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = activePaint;
        break;
    }

    // Used to create a gap around the thumb iff the slider is disabled.
    // If the slider is enabled, the track can be drawn beneath the thumb
    // without a gap. But when the slider is disabled, the track is shortened
    // and this gap helps determine how much shorter it should be.
    // TODO(clocksmith): The new Material spec has a gray circle in place of this gap.
    double horizontalAdjustment = 0.0;
    if (!isEnabled) {
      final double disabledThumbRadius = sliderTheme.thumbShape.getPreferredSize(false, isDiscrete).width / 2.0;
      final double gap = disabledThumbGapWidth * (1.0 - enableAnimation.value);
      horizontalAdjustment = disabledThumbRadius + gap;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
        parentBox: parentBox,
        offset: offset,
        sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
        isEnabled: isEnabled,
        isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );
    final Rect leftTrackSegment = Rect.fromLTRB(trackRect.left, trackRect.top, thumbCenter.dx - horizontalAdjustment, trackRect.bottom);

    // Left Arc
    context.canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
      -pi * 3 / 2, // -270 degrees
      pi, // 180 degrees
      false,
      trackRect.left - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? rightTrackPaint : leftTrackPaint
    );

    // Right Arc
    context.canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.right, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
      -pi / 2, // -90 degrees
      pi, // 180 degrees
      false,
      trackRect.right - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? leftTrackPaint : rightTrackPaint
    );

    context.canvas.drawRect(leftTrackSegment, leftTrackPaint);
    final Rect rightTrackSegment = Rect.fromLTRB(thumbCenter.dx + horizontalAdjustment, trackRect.top, trackRect.right, trackRect.bottom);
    context.canvas.drawRect(rightTrackSegment, rightTrackPaint);
  }
}
```

The following is how the SliderTheme is setup.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_stackoverflow/round_slider_track_shape.dart';
...
sliderTheme: Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.copyWith(
  trackHeight: 22.0,
  trackShape: RoundSliderTrackShape(),
  activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
  // trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
),
```

What was added was two circle arcs to the side of the SliderTrack

```
// Left Arc
context.canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
  -pi * 3 / 2, // -270 degrees
  pi, // 180 degrees
  false,
  trackRect.left - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? rightTrackPaint : leftTrackPaint
);

// Right Arc
context.canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.right, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
  -pi / 2, // -90 degrees
  pi, // 180 degrees
  false,
  trackRect.right - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? leftTrackPaint : rightTrackPaint
);
```

Comment: with your answer, I was able to unlock the key to updating the other painting too like tick mark shape, and thumb shape. thanks!!!  (see updated image in the question)

Comment: You might also want to use `NoThumbShape` in this design

Answer (score 5):

Answer by @Jun Xiang seems to work but I did a minor change in the following code:

```
// Left Arc

context.canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
  -pi * 3 / 2, // -270 degrees
  pi, // 180 degrees
  false,
  trackRect.left - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? rightTrackPaint : leftTrackPaint
);

// Right Arc

context.canvas.drawArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(trackRect.right, trackRect.top + 11.0), radius: 11.0),
  -pi / 2, // -90 degrees
  pi, // 180 degrees
  false,
  trackRect.right - thumbCenter.dx == 0.0 ? leftTrackPaint : rightTrackPaint
);
```

Instead of using **11.0** I used **sliderTheme.trackHeight * 1/2** and seems to work for all track heights entered (not only 22).

PS: I couldn't comment so I posted an answer.

Comment: Yup, good point.  I did quickly notice that as I was using this solution so better to make it generic.  This solution was very helpful for me to understand how to get into the guts of these material widgets and "paint" whatever I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Create custom shape like this, In this i am drawing 2 circles on thumb

```
    class SliderThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  /// Create a slider thumb that draws a circle.

  const SliderThumbShape({
    this.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0,
    this.disabledThumbRadius,
    this.elevation = 1.0,
    this.pressedElevation = 6.0,
  });

  /// The preferred radius of the round thumb shape when the slider is enabled.
  ///
  /// If it is not provided, then the material default of 10 is used.
  final double enabledThumbRadius;

  /// The preferred radius of the round thumb shape when the slider is disabled.
  ///
  /// If no disabledRadius is provided, then it is equal to the
  /// [enabledThumbRadius]
  final double disabledThumbRadius;
  double get _disabledThumbRadius => disabledThumbRadius ?? enabledThumbRadius;

  /// The resting elevation adds shadow to the unpressed thumb.
  ///
  /// The default is 1.
  ///
  /// Use 0 for no shadow. The higher the value, the larger the shadow. For
  /// example, a value of 12 will create a very large shadow.
  ///
  final double elevation;

  /// The pressed elevation adds shadow to the pressed thumb.
  ///
  /// The default is 6.
  ///
  /// Use 0 for no shadow. The higher the value, the larger the shadow. For
  /// example, a value of 12 will create a very large shadow.
  final double pressedElevation;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(isEnabled == true ? enabledThumbRadius : _disabledThumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
        Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        @required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        bool isDiscrete,
        TextPainter labelPainter,
        RenderBox parentBox,
        @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        TextDirection textDirection,
        double value,
        double textScaleFactor,
        Size sizeWithOverflow,
      }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(center != null);
    assert(enableAnimation != null);
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.thumbColor != null);
    assert(!sizeWithOverflow.isEmpty);

    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Tween<double> radiusTween = Tween<double>(
      begin: _disabledThumbRadius,
      end: enabledThumbRadius,
    );

    final double radius = radiusTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);

    final Tween<double> elevationTween = Tween<double>(
      begin: elevation,
      end: pressedElevation,
    );

    final double evaluatedElevation = elevationTween.evaluate(activationAnimation);

    {
      final Path path = Path()
        ..addArc(Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 1 * radius, height: 1 * radius), 0, math.pi * 2);

      Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.black;
      paint.strokeWidth = 15;
      paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
      canvas.drawCircle(
        center,
        radius,
        paint,
      );
      {
        Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
        paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
        canvas.drawCircle(
          center,
          radius,
          paint,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it in your widget tree like this

```
SliderTheme(
                                data: SliderThemeData(
                                  activeTrackColor: Colors.blue,
                                  inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xffd0d2d3),
                                  trackHeight: 2,
                                  thumbShape: SliderThumbShape(),
                                ),
                                child: Slider(
                                  onChanged: (value) {},
                                  value: 40.5,
                                  max: 100,
                                  min: 0,
                                ),
                              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default `trackShape` for slider is now a `RoundedRectSliderTrackShape` in master branch:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart#L462

Does that work for you?

`RectangularSliderTrackShape` can be preserved by overriding the `trackShape` in the SliderThemeData.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that would have worked as well!  I have been watching the google io 19 on youtube, and see that they've released a new flutter and updates like this above so this is great!  I also must say though, the original answer was perfect for me to learn how to control my own widget painting.  I needed that for the tick mark shapes and the thumb shape too!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I have a better solution

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class RoundSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {

      const RoundSliderTrackShape({this.disabledThumbGapWidth = 2.0, this.radius = 0});

      final double disabledThumbGapWidth;
      final double radius;

      @override
      Rect getPreferredRect({
        RenderBox parentBox,
        Offset offset = Offset.zero,
        SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        bool isEnabled,
        bool isDiscrete,
      }) {
        final double overlayWidth = sliderTheme.overlayShape.getPreferredSize(isEnabled, isDiscrete).width;
        final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
        assert(overlayWidth >= 0);
        assert(trackHeight >= 0);
        assert(parentBox.size.width >= overlayWidth);
        assert(parentBox.size.height >= trackHeight);

        final double trackLeft = offset.dx + overlayWidth / 2;
        final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;

        final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - overlayWidth;
        return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
      }

      @override
      void paint(
        PaintingContext context,
        Offset offset, {
        RenderBox parentBox,
        SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        TextDirection textDirection,
        Offset thumbCenter,
        bool isDiscrete,
        bool isEnabled,
      }) {
        if (sliderTheme.trackHeight == 0) {
          return;
        }

        final ColorTween activeTrackColorTween =
            ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor, end: sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
        final ColorTween inactiveTrackColorTween =
            ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor, end: sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor);
        final Paint activePaint = Paint()..color = activeTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
        final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()..color = inactiveTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation);
        Paint leftTrackPaint;
        Paint rightTrackPaint;
        switch (textDirection) {
          case TextDirection.ltr:
            leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
            rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
            break;
          case TextDirection.rtl:
            leftTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
            rightTrackPaint = activePaint;
            break;
        }

        double horizontalAdjustment = 0.0;
        if (!isEnabled) {
          final double disabledThumbRadius =
              sliderTheme.thumbShape.getPreferredSize(false, isDiscrete).width / 2.0;
          final double gap = disabledThumbGapWidth * (1.0 - enableAnimation.value);
          horizontalAdjustment = disabledThumbRadius + gap;
        }

        final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
          parentBox: parentBox,
          offset: offset,
          sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
          isEnabled: isEnabled,
          isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
        );
        //Modify this side
        final RRect leftTrackSegment = RRect.fromLTRBR(trackRect.left, trackRect.top,
            thumbCenter.dx - horizontalAdjustment, trackRect.bottom, Radius.circular(radius));
        context.canvas.drawRRect(leftTrackSegment, leftTrackPaint);
        final RRect rightTrackSegment = RRect.fromLTRBR(thumbCenter.dx + horizontalAdjustment, trackRect.top,
            trackRect.right, trackRect.bottom, Radius.circular(radius));
        context.canvas.drawRRect(rightTrackSegment, rightTrackPaint);
      }
    }
```

use:

```
trackShape: RoundSliderTrackShape(radius: 8)
```

Comment: In addition to providing code, also add some explanation to what your code does

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to draw a thick line with a round `StrokeCap`. The cap radius at the two ends is in addition to the line width.

```
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset,
      {required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required Offset thumbCenter,
      bool isEnabled = true,
      bool isDiscrete = true,
      required TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final width = 200;
    final height = 16;

    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(0, height / 2),
        Offset(width, height / 2),
        Paint()
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..strokeWidth = height);
  }
```