# flutter slider edge does not use radius

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

In the code below, I want to give a fixed radius to the edge of the slider, but when the thumb moves to the edge, the radius disappears and becomes angular.

```
Container(
            width: 370,
            height: 62,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                )),
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderThemeData(
                trackHeight: 60,
                trackShape:  RoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
                thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
                overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
                valueIndicatorShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
                thumbColor: Colors.transparent,
                activeTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Slider(
                value: _sliderValue,
                min: 0.0,
                max: 100.0,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _sliderValue = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I round the corners of a slider in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987559/how-can-i-round-the-corners-of-a-slider-in-flutter)

Comment: It's a pretty old title and there are a lot of errors, especially in the null section. It confused me. I aim to open the issue again and get a better answer.

Comment: Yeah agree, I think those are very sketchy workaround. My workaround is to wrap with Transform.scale with scaleX and then wrap it with ClipRRect. I can write the answer if you don't mind that.

Comment: A separate project is required for testing anyway. If you post a code I can reject it quickly. There is almost no code in the project other than the code I handed over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's no way to do it with the provided `SliderThemeData` options. The minimal workaround is to use `ClipRRect` to clip the border of your slider widget to rounded shape, and use `Transform.scale` to "remove" the internal padding from the slider so that the left & right sides are clipped correctly.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
  child: Transform.scale(
    scaleX: 1.2,
    child: Slider(
      // ...
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: this code works. thanks a lot. I wish it were easier to do this in Flutter through legal means, but this will do.